# Why it's impossible to throw exception from __toString()?

Tags: php, exception

Why it's impossible to throw exception from __toString()?

```
class a
{
    public function __toString()
    {
        throw new Exception();
    }
}

$a = new a();
echo $a;
```

the code above produces this:

```
Fatal error: Method a::__toString() must not throw an exception in /var/www/localhost/htdocs/index.php on line 12
```

I was pointed to http://php.net/manual/en/migration52.incompatible.php where this behavior is described, but why? Any reasons to do that?

May be anyone here knows this?

At bug tracker php-dev-team as usual says nothing but see manual: http://bugs.php.net/50699

Comment: PHP 7.4 now [allows exceptions](https://www.php.net/manual/en/migration74.new-features.php#migration74.new-features.core.tostring-exceptions) in `__toString()`

Answer (score 48, accepted):

After a couple searches I found this, which says:

> Johannes explained that **there is no way to ensure that an exception thrown during a cast to string would be handled correctly by the Zend Engine**, and that this won't change unless large parts of the Engine are rewritten. He added that there have been discussions about such issues in the past, and suggested that Guilherme check the archives.

The [Johannes](http://schlueters.de/) referenced above is the PHP 5.3 Release Manager, so it's probably as "official" an explanation as you might find as to why PHP behaves this way.

The section goes on to mention:

> `__toString()` will, strangely enough, accept [trigger_error()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.trigger-error.php).

So not all is lost in terms of error reporting within `__toString()`.

Comment: heh, thanx. but trigger_error() cannot replace try/catch just because it's global and try/catch is concrete.

Comment: @zerkms - It's true, it's no replacement. Maybe if enough people voice their opinions they'll rewrite the Zend Engine. :)

Comment: also, many frameworks catch errors and re-throw them as exceptions - which would bring back the exact same problem.

Comment: This deserves a big WAT

Comment: Actually, if you explicitly call __toString(), so **echo $a->__toString();** will successfully pass the exception as a fatal error where **echo $a;** will not.

Answer (score 10):

My guess would be that `__toString` is hackish and therefore exists outside of the typical stack. A thrown exception, then, wouldn't know where to go.

Comment: especially since `echo $a->__toString()` can throw an exception, but `echo $a` cannot.

Comment: __toString is not hackish, it's a completely standard way of providing a string representation of an object. The difference between (string)$a and $a->__toString() is in the way that the engine handles your calls, it's the same as the differences between $x->something and $x->__call("something"). One is a direct call to a function in the object (a function that happens to start with __) and the other is a magic method handled internally by the Zend engine.

Comment: @Sprog I think the *hackish* term was being applied that its implementation is hackish.

Answer (score 9):

in response to the accepted answer, I came up with a (perhaps) better way to handle exceptions inside `__toString()`:

```
public function __toString()
{
    try {
        // ... do some stuff
        // and try to return a string
        $string = $this->doSomeStuff();
        if (!is_string($string)) {
            // we must throw an exception manually here because if $value
            // is not a string, PHP will trigger an error right after the
            // return statement, thus escaping our try/catch.
            throw new \LogicException(__CLASS__ . "__toString() must return a string");
        }

        return $string;
    } catch (\Exception $exception) {
        $previousHandler = set_exception_handler(function (){
        });
        restore_error_handler();
        call_user_func($previousHandler, $exception);
        die;
    }
}
```

This assumes there is an exception handler defined, which is the case for most frameworks. As with the `trigger_error` method, **doing this will defy the purpose of try..catch**, but still it is much better than dumping output with `echo`. Also, many framework transform errors into exceptions, so `trigger_error` won't work anyway.

As an added bonus, you'll get a full stack-trace as with normal exceptions and the normal dev-production behaviour of your framework of choice.

Works very well in Laravel, and I'm pretty sure it'll work in pretty much all the modern PHP frameworks out there.

Screenshot relevant:
*note*: in this example, `output()` is called by a `__toString()` method.

[image: __toString() exception caught by Laravel exception handler]

Answer (score 5):

It seems that as of php 7.4 throwing exception from __toString() is allowed. I had a php7.2 compatibility check and it said so and pointed the Doctrine [StaticReflectionClass](https://www.doctrine-project.org/api/reflection/latest/Doctrine/Common/Reflection/StaticReflectionClass.html#method___toString) and [StaticReflectionProperty](https://www.doctrine-project.org/api/reflection/latest/Doctrine/Common/Reflection/StaticReflectionProperty.html#method___toString).

Please find more information about the proposal https://wiki.php.net/rfc/tostring_exceptions

Answer (score 1):

Since **PHP 7.4** this problem has been fixed. [Migration article](https://www.php.net/manual/en/migration74.new-features.php#migration74.new-features.core.tostring-exceptions) describing all the changes in PHP 7.4, including this one.

THE RFC that contains more details about the past problem: [RFC](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/tostring_exceptions)

Example:

```
class TopSecret {
    public function __toString() {
        throw new Exception('You are not allowed to print this confidential information!');
    }
}

print new TopSecret();
```

Answer (score -1):

I don't think the rationale for this decision has ever been publicized. Looks like some internal architectural limitation.

On a more abstract level, it kind of makes sense. An object should be able to return a string representation of itself, no reason for that kind of action to fail.

Comment: "An object should be able to return a string representation of itself, no reason for that kind of action to fail." hehe :-) echo $a->__toString(); throws it ;-) and this is expected. in this case method also should be able to return something casted to string, but no, we get unhandled exception.

Comment: The exception you get is not thrown from within `__toString()`

Comment: But i mean "An object should be able to return a string representation of itself" should be true also for "a method should be able to return something to echo" as you mentioned. but it's false. ps: the exception i got was thrown from __toString()

Comment: No it was not, you are receiving an exception when trying to invoke a method which does not exist on non-object `$a`

Comment: class a
{
    public function __toString()
    {
        throw new Exception();
    }
}

$a = new a();
echo $a->__toString();

huh? when object not exists it's a fatal error (and notice), not an exception

Comment: @zerkms That's exactly because directly calling it is fine, it exists within the bounds of normal call procedures, while toString can be called in the middle of other things being processed (any time you need a string and passed an object) and handling exception there would require a lot of work in order to ensure exception can be handled at any point in the engine, rather than on method call boundaries as it is now.

Answer (score -1):

I found simple solution:

Just return something like non-string type in __toString when error conversion to string occurs: NULL, FALSE or even Exception.

This will cause output like this (in php -a interactive SHELL):

```
Catchable fatal error: Method MyClass::__toString() must return a string value in php shell code on line 1
```

Comment: Its work for me: when getting fatal error on conversion in __toString is unwanted. Then the catchable fatal error can be processed instead just getting only fatal error in __toString

Comment: I'm not sure if you have read the question or not. Just to remind you: I asked **WHY** it's impossible to do so.