# __toString() must not throw an exception error when using string

Tags: php, laravel

I am using Laravel 4 for a project I am working on. I need to retrieve the first comment from the post. I use the following code to do so.

```
$comments = Comment::where('post_id', $post->id)->first();
```

This successfully retrieves the first comment (I know that because I `print_r`-ed `$comments` and it returned all the right information).

However, the following line of code triggers the error `__toString() must not throw an exception`

```
<td>{{$comments->content}}</td>
```

When I `print_r`-ed that it returned type string, and returned the correct string as well. Why then would it even try to convert `$comments->content` to type string when it is already a string?

Comment: It says that `__toString()` method of a `View` class must not throw an exception. Probably, you have some error in your view

Comment: Is this your question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2429642/why-its-impossible-to-throw-exception-from-tostring

Comment: `Symfony \ Component \ Debug \ Exception \ FatalErrorException
Method Illuminate\View\View::__toString() must not throw an exception` is the full error @neoascetic. Also, what kind of error would that be?

Comment: @735Tesla that doesn't tell me what I'm doing wrong

Comment: @InsertNameHere Undefined variable. Unclosed curly brace. Any kind of error, in fact

Comment: @neoascetic I am aware how easy it is to make those kinds of mistakes (in fact I was working on a project with someone and they switched around the if statement so for a while we were stuck ;), but I have check my code, and I also have `<td>{{ $post->contents }}</td>` right above the `$comment` td and that code works when I take out the `$comment` part.

Comment: Have you passed `$comments` variable to the view?

Comment: @735Tesla actually I have been googling all night, and I am a beginner in php. I have searched the forums, and through all that googling and searching, I didn't figure out the problem, so I decided to ask for help in this 'friendly' community ;)

Comment: @neoascetic that was a typo in my other comment. That should be `$comments` not `$comment`

Comment: @735Tesla could you please explain to me what the link that you posted's solution means if you think its the right answer?

Comment: @InsertNameHere so have you passed the variable?

Comment: @neoascetic what do you mean?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Based off the information you've given and my experience with Laravel I'd bet that the line of code causing the exception is **not** the line you've put in your question.

```
<td>{{$comments->content}}</td>
```

This exception is complaining about the view throwing an exception.  If this particular line was the issue you'd get a more descriptive exception about how $comments->content can't be converted into a string.  You've also already tested that it is indeed a string.

I'd recommend finding where your "View" object is being echoed to the view and change it like so.

```
{{ View::make('yourbladefile')->__tostring() }}
```

This worked for me by providing a more accurate and informative exception.  For more info on your exception you should check out [Why it's impossible to throw exception from __toString()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2429642/why-its-impossible-to-throw-exception-from-tostring)

It's what gave me the idea in the first place.  I know it's not a perfect answer so please let me know if this works and I'll update my answer if this turns out not be the case.  Good luck.

Comment: This is a great tip!  I was able to peel back the exception chain by using var_dump($somevar) until I found the root of my problem (which was an uninitialized relationship).

Answer (score 2):

I know that this is an old question, but for future googlers (like me) there is another way to solve that error, and it is independent of your framework:

```
public function __toString() 
{
    try {
       return (string) $this->attributeToReturn; // If it is possible, return a string value from object.
    } catch (Exception $e) {
       return get_class($this).'@'.spl_object_hash($this); // If it is not possible, return a preset string to identify instance of object, e.g.
    }
}
```

You can use it with your custom class with no framework, or with an entity in Symfony2/Doctrine... It will work as well.