# Submit multiple form to a controller

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

My web application generates a certain amount of forms to register users on user input.that is if the user input 2, the page generates two forms or any number the user inputs.And i submit the form to the controller with a single submit button since am creating several users.but when i click the submit button i laravel throws error **"Method Applicant::__toString() must not throw an exception".**

Can't figure what am doing wrong.below here is the code.

**create.blade.php**

```
@for($i=1; $i < $num + 1; $i++)
 <form method="POST" action="{{URL::route('quickform.store')}}" class="user form-horizontal" enctype="multipart/form-data">

<input type="hidden" name="formnumber" value="{{$num}}">
   <!--surname and othernames-->
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-sm-1 col-md-offset-">        
        <label for="name">Surname</label>        
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-3">
        <input type="text" name="{{'surname'.$num}}" required value="{{Input::old('surname')}}" class="form-control">

        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-1 col-md-offset-">        
        <label for="name">Other Names</label>        
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-3">
        <input type="text" name="{{'othernames'.$num}}" required value="{{Input::old('othernames')}}" class="form-control">
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-1 col-md-offset-">        
        <label for="occupation">Occupation</label>        
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-3">
        <input type="text" name="{{'occupation'.$num}}" required value="{{Input::old('occupation')}}" class="form-control">
        </div>
    </div>

<!--address and LGA-->
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-sm-1 col-md-offset-">        
        <label for="address">Address</label>        
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-3">
        <input type="text" name="{{'address'.$num}}" required value="{{Input::old('address')}}" class="form-control">
        </div>
         <div class="col-sm-1 col-md-offset-">        
        <label for="dob">DOB</label>        
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-3">
        <input type="date" name="{{'dob'.$num}}" value="{{Input::old('dob')}}" required class="form-control" class="form-control">
        </div>
       <div class="col-sm-1 col-md-offset-">        
        <label for="phone">Phone</label>        
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-3">
        <input type="text" name="{{'phone'.$num}}" required value="{{Input::old('phone')}}" class="form-control">
        </div>
    </div>
<!--sex DOB GENOTYPE BLOOD GROUP-->
<div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-sm-1 col-md-offset-">        
        <label for="sex">Sex</label>        
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-1">
        <label for="sex">M&nbsp;</label><input type="radio" name="{{'sex'.$num}}" value="M">
        <label for="sex">F&nbsp;</label><input type="radio" name="{{'sex'.$num}}" value="F">
        </div>
<div class="col-sm-1 col-md-offset-">        
        <label for="reg_frm">Collector</label>        
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-2">
            <select name="{{'collector'.$num}}" required>
        <option value="">CHOOSE--COLLECTOR</option>
            @foreach($collectors as $collector)
        <option value="{{strtoupper($collector->name)}}">{{$collector->name}}</option>
        @endforeach
    </select>
    </div>

    <div class="col-sm-1 col-md-offset-1">        
        <label for="reg_frm">Validity From:</label>        
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-2">
        <input type="date" name="{{'reg_frm'.$num}}" value="{{Input::old('reg_frm')}}" class="form-control" required>
        </div>

        <div class="col-sm-1 col-md-offset-">        
        <label for="reg_to">To</label>        
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-2">
        <input type="date" name="{{'reg_to'.$num}}" value="{{Input::old('reg_no')}}" class="form-control" required>
        </div>
  </div>     

<div class="form-group">
        <div  class="col-sm-1">      
        <label for="form_no">Form NO.</label>        
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-1">
        <input type="text" name="{{'form_no'.$num}}" value="{{Input::old('form_no')}}" class="form-control" required>
        </div>

        <div class="col-sm-1 col-md-offset-">        
        <label for="tell_no">Reciept NO.</label>        
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-1">
        <input type="text" name="{{'tell_no'.$num}}" value="{{Input::old('tell_no')}}" class="form-control" required>
        </div>

        <div class="col-sm-1">        
        <label for="amt_paid">Amount Paid</label>        
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-1">
        <input type="text" name="{{'amt_paid'.$num}}" value="{{Input::old('amt_paid')}}" class="form-control" required>
    </div>
     <div class="col-sm-1">        
        <label for="LGA">LGA</label>     
        </div>

        <div class="col-sm-2">
        <select onchange="quickfacility('{{URL::to('/quickfacility')}}','{{'facility'.$i}}','{{'lga'.$i}}')" id="{{'lga'.$i}}" name="lga" class="form-control" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="">
        <option value="">Choose-LGA</option>
        @foreach($LGA as $key => $F_LGA)
        <option id="{{'fac'.$key}}" data-lg="{{$F_LGA->id}}" value="{{$F_LGA->LGA_Name}}">{{$F_LGA->LGA_Name}}</option>
        @endforeach
        </select>
         </div>
         <div id="{{'facility'.$i}}">
         </div>
</div>
<hr style="color:black;height:2px;border:black 1px solid">
<br>
@endfor
```

**formController.php**

```
public function store()
    {
        $num = Input::get('formnumber');

        for($i = 1; $i < $num + 1; $i++)
        {


                $applicant.$i=new Applicant;

                $applicant->surname     = strtoupper(Input::get('surname'.$num));
                $applicant->othernames  = strtoupper(Input::get('othernames'.$num));
                $applicant->address     = strtoupper(Input::get('address'.$num));
                $applicant->lga         = strtoupper(Input::get('lga'.$num));
                $applicant->sex         = strtoupper(Input::get('sex'.$num));
                $applicant->dob         = strtoupper(Input::get('dob'.$num));
                $applicant->genotype    = strtoupper(Input::get('genotype'.$num));
                $applicant->blood_grp   = strtoupper(Input::get('blood_grp'.$num));
                $applicant->phone       = strtoupper(Input::get('phone'.$num));
                $applicant->email       = strtoupper(Input::get('email'.$num));
                $applicant->occupation  = strtoupper(Input::get('occupation'.$num));
                $applicant->place_emp   = strtoupper(Input::get('place_emp'.$num));
                $applicant->facility    = strtoupper(Input::get('facility'.$num));
                $applicant->medical_his = strtoupper(Input::get('medical_his'.$num));
                $applicant->allergy     = strtoupper(Input::get('allergy'.$num));
                $applicant->reg_frm     = strtoupper(Input::get('reg_frm'.$num));
                $applicant->reg_to      = strtoupper(Input::get('reg_to'.$num));
                $applicant->collector   = strtoupper(Input::get('collector'.$num));
                $applicant->form_no     = strtoupper(Input::get('form_no'.$num));
                $applicant->tell_no     = strtoupper(Input::get('tell_no'.$num));
                $applicant->amt_paid    = strtoupper(Input::get('amt_paid'.$num));
                }

                for($i = 1; $i < $num + 1; $i++)
                {
                $applicant=$applicant.$i;
                $applicant->save();
                }

                return Redirect::to('/')->with('success','Applications successfully created');

            }
```

Thanks in advance
I have no intention in validating the data

Comment: Please show your `Applicant` Model.

Comment: Maybe this will help you out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21104373/tostring-must-not-throw-an-exception-error-when-using-string

Comment: Also read through your stack trace. Do you know at what point this is failing in your controller?